# My R class is not creating ids of my UI elements

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

This is the image of my `main_avtivity`:
[image: this is the image of my main_avtivity]

This is the image of my `activity_main.xml` layout:
[image: this is the image of my activity_main.xml layout]

I have imported `com.example.calculator.R` class. I even tried to clean the project so many times. I even made a new Project two times. Moreover my `ADT Plugin` is properly installed. Plz help me. I have done everything mentioned in other `StackOverflow` answers but nothing seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 1):

`R.java` won't generate properly if there are errors in your XML files. So look through your XML files and look for any possible issues. The errors in the console at the bottom of your second screenshot would be a good place to start.

Comment: yes,i found an error at this line    android:textColor="@color/white"     in textview please tell me what's the error in it

Comment: Do you have `<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>` declared in your `colors.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

First SaveAll your changes then go to project>Clean Project and Build it again. Its seems like you didn't save your project.